# How to get new update merged to a repo on my local machine?

Tags: github

How do delete a cloned git repo from my local machine to reclone with the new updates merged to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think deleting a repository and recloning it is a good method to update a repo. Instead, you can do this by directly pulling the updates from the central repo to your local repo.

```
git pull upstream master
```